# pyqt4: QListWidget: How to set different text and background colors to different items dynamically

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I am new to PyQt. I want to design a list which will show different items with different background and text color. I am able to add items to my list but could not configure them to set different colors.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(786, 552)
        self.mylist = QtGui.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.mylist.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mylist"))


        self.mylist.addItem("item1")


        self.mylist.addItem("item2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My above code added to item named item1 and item2 in mylist. I want to set background color and text color to item1 blue and white ,and to item2 red and black. how could i do that??

Comment: yes sir, it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QListWidgetItem` class has the [`setBackground()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html#setBackground):

```
QListWidgetItem.setBackground(your_color)
```

In your case:

```
self.mylist.item(0).setBackground(QtCore.Qt.blue)
# self.mylist.item(0).setBackground(QtGui.QColor("blue"))
# self.mylist.item(0).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
self.mylist.item(1).setBackground(QtCore.Qt.white)
# self.mylist.item(1).setBackground(QtGui.QColor("white"))
# self.mylist.item(1).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
```

Comment: thank's a lot. it's working. please tell me how to set text(font) color

Comment: font color is not changing

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna change the font color, use the property called `setForeground`

`self.mylist.item(0).setForeground(QtCore.Qt.blue)`

This will change the font color to blue, for item 0